# How to write an exception for nil or empty string in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Started learning Ruby a week ago. The most frustrating part so far has been exception handling. Been looking for an example for what I want to do for hours.

I am looping through an array of API codes, grabbing text via Net::Http. Sometimes the grab returns nil or empty, and I'm trying to test for it in a way that will let me retry the grab on that exception until it works.

I am fairly certain I need to do something like

```
array.each do |api_key|
  begin
   result = # the code to grab the page via the API key

   if result.empty or result.nil
     raise SomeKindOfExceptionThing
   end

  rescue SomeKindOfExceptionThing
    puts "some error message"
    retry

  else
    # Act on the valid return for result
  end
end
```

I have no idea how to properly form this so it does what I want. Most of the documentation I've found on exceptions is for handling predefined types of errors or just a generic `rescue`.

Comment: Please, read the documentation carefully. The methods are named `nil?` and `empty?` not `nil` and `empty`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @eugen says your code will work. Not sure I see much benefit in raising the exception, though, in that particular example.

```
array.each do |api_key|
  result = # the code to grab the page via the API key 
  if result.empty || result.nil
    puts "some error message"
    redo
  end
  # Act on the valid return for result
end
```

Comment: I think you confuse `retry` and `redo`.

Comment: Indeed; `retry` will go through all api keys again in case of an error, `redo` will only repeat the failed ones. +1 for doubting exceptions: they are the mechanism for non-local error handling. Instead of raising an exception and immediately rescuing it, `if` is much easier, shorter, and more performant.

Comment: @Stefan absolutely.  I copied OP's code and didn't spot the mistake. Answer edited.

Comment: @Amadan absolutely.  I copied OP's code and didn't spot the mistake. Answer edited.

Comment: I didn't know you could repeat a loop iteration without an exception. This is great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, you just need to define your exception class.
Something like

```
class SomeKindOfExceptionThing < StandardError
end
```

should be enough (you might need a better name, though).